# How can I benchmark NFS and SMB transfer speeds?

Tags: nfs, benchmark, smb

I'd like to compare the speeds of NFS and SMB across my network.  Is there any good (and simple) tool to let me do this?  Ideally I'd like something I can just point at my mounted filesystem (i.e. /nfs/fileserver/test_folder) and have it run a couple of tests for maximum read/write throughput and whatever else tests it can perform?

Comment: Check `bonnie++`. It can be used on hard disks, but also on file systems.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous tools you can use to benchmark like `fio`, `iometer`, `vdbench` but also tools like `dd`, `cat`, `tar` and `mkfile` (Solaris) can be of great assistance. In combination with `nfsstat`, `cifsiostat`, `iostat`, `iotop`, `fsstat` and `smbstat` (last two I use on Solaris) you are able to get a lot of detailed info about IO/s and troughput.

Another important thing is to know where your load is coming from. The storage and/or service is often blamed for being slow where in fact the originating party is to blame.

For instance, if you read from a slow disk and try to write to SAN based storage, the client is the limiting factor. Besides that it might be necessary to start multiple workers because one stream or worker might be limited.

Another example, if you try to stress an NFS server from a client with a 10Mbs connection, the client is to blame and most probably not the NFS server.

So keep in mind which hardware and software you are using for the tests.